# Databases not linking using hasMany in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to use data from two databases in laravel. Edit: I have added the products controller to the bottom of this post

This is how I test if they are linked:

```
<p>TEST :{{ $products->ticket->created_at}}</p>
```

error message:

> Undefined variable: products (View: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/lsapp/resources/views/products/create.blade.php)

**Product.php (App)**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    //Table NAME
    protected $table = 'products';

    //PRIMARY KEY
    public $primaryKey = 'id';

    //Timestamps
    public $timestamps =true;

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(App\product::class);
    }
}
```

**Ticket.php (app)**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class product extends Model
{
    public function Product(){
        return $this->belongsTo(App\Product::class);
    }
}
```

**Product Controller:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\product;
use App\Ticket;

class productController extends Controller
{
        /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth',['except' => ['index','show']]);
    }

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $products = product::orderBy('created_at','desc')->paginate(10);
        //$products = product::where('type','major')->get();
        return view('products.index')->with('products',$products);
    } 

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('products.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[
            'title' => 'required',
        ]);
            //create product
        $product = new product;
        $product->title = $request->input('title');
        $product->venue = $request->input('venue');
        $product->city = $request->input('city');
        $product->country = $request->input('country');
        $product->description = $request->input('description');
        $product->date = $request->input('date');
        $product->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
        $product->save();

        return redirect('/products')->with('success','product Created');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        $product = product::find($id);
        return view('products.show')->with('product',$product);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $product = product::find($id);

        if(auth()->user()->id !==$product->user_id){
            return redirect('/products')->with('error','unauthorised page');
        }

        return view('products.edit')->with('product',$product);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'title' => 'required'
        ]);

        $product = product::find($id);
        $product->title = $request->input('title');
        $product->venue = $request->input('venue');
        $product->city = $request->input('city');
        $product->country = $request->input('country');
        $product->description = $request->input('description');
        $product->date = $request->input('date');
        $product->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
        $product->save();

        return redirect('/products')->with('success','product updated');
    }


    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $product = product::find($id);
        if(auth()->user()->id !==$product->user_id){
            return redirect('/products')->with('error','unauthorised page');
        }

        $product->delete();
        return redirect('/products')->with('success','product deleted');

    }
}
```

Comment: How are you passing the $product to the view? Show the code in your controller please? Also, your Product model doesn't have a relation ship with ticket.

Comment: @pseudoanime added the controller

Comment: You are not sending the products variable into the view, hence the error. you need to add ->with('product',$product) at the end of your return statement to access the variable & the variable needs to be populated.Why do you have a product variable in the create view anyway?

Comment: @pseudoanime was testing to see if it worked. following this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bo3m_h0QYkU

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your code.

`<p>TEST :{{ $products->ticket->created_at}}</p>` will never work.
Assuming you are testing in your index page, you need to loop over each product in order to see it's relationship with a ticket. 
Do all of your products have a single ticket? If so, then you can just define the single ticket in a config variable. It does not make sense to define a many-to-one relationship in a database.

In your `Product` model, you have not defined a relationship to the `Ticket` model. You only have a relationship defined in the `Ticket` model to the `Product` model. This means that you can access a `product` from the `ticket`, but not the other way around. You need to explicitly define a one-on-one relationship from `Product` to `Ticket` in order to use it.

You have defined this function within the Product model.

```
public function products() {

    return $this->hasMany(App\product::class);
}
```

Why? Do products themselves have many products? I think you may benefit from learning about eloquent relationships. Laracasts is a good resource for learning Laravel from scratch.
Also see [Laravel official Eloquent documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one)